# Liferay 6.2: SassToCssBuilder has got NullPointerException,

Tags: liferay, portlet

Now, I have problem when I build portlet to war file in eclipse.

Env: 
- liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2.0 
- liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2

Issue: use eclipse to build the portlet to **war file successfully, but I have the error:** 
build-css: 
[java] Loading jar:file:/home/tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties 
[java] Loading jar:file:/home/tomcat-7.0.53/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties 
[java] java.lang.NullPointerException 
[java] at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder._parseSassDirectory(**SassToCssBuilder.java:222**) 
[java] at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder.(SassToCssBuilder.java:144) 
[java] at com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder.main(SassToCssBuilder.java:94)

**Please, give me any suggestion to fix this problem!**

I am waiting for all you help! 
Thanks and Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause is the Tomcat-server that I changed. So, I have to use the tomcat-server of Liferay to build the portlet to pass that error.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out the goal `build-css` as mentioned here [enter link description here](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/MAVEN-160)

> we want to just forward that request to the CSSBuilderMojo and not require the invoking from jars in portal directory

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>          
      <!--<execution>-->
        <!--<phase>generate-sources</phase>-->
        <!--<goals>-->
          <!--<goal>build-css</goal>-->
        <!--</goals>-->
      <!--</execution>-->
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```